# New updated image in the bucket is not showing in client side unless i open an icognito window

Tags: supabase

I'm having some issues when i update an image at front. When i update an image using the updating function from `supabase` it updates the image data properly keeping the file name (the same file name stored into the db) but in the client side the change made into the bucket does not comes up unless i open a new incognito window. The function that  i'm using for update the bucket was taken from `supabase` docs, the only way to see the image updated in client side is disabling cache in dev tools in the browser.

```
const { data, error } = await supabase
.storage
.from('avatars')
.update('public/avatar1.png', avatarFile)
```

I don't know why is this happening

Answer (score 1):

> the only way to see the image updated in client side is disabling cache in dev tools in the browser

You have the answer right there! The cause is your browser caching your image.

One thing you could do is to use a lower value for cacheControl header when uploading your image. In this example, we have 5 min cache max age.

```js
const { data, error } = await supabase
  .storage
  .from('avatars')
  .upload('public/avatar1.png', avatarFile, {
    cacheControl: '300', // The image will be cached for 5 minutes
    upsert: false
  })
```

But this comes with some down side such as your service requesting for the original image more often than necessary. What I recommend doing is to modify the image URL.

For example, if you have an image URL like this

`https://example.com/images/profile.png`

You could manually add a random query parameter to create a new URL

`https://example.com/images/profile.png?c=1`

Comment: Hi, i did a kind of workaround. deleting the old image and uploading the new one when the user save the edited post.

Comment: @Richi Hmm, if it's cached on the browser, not sure if that works, but if it's working for you, happy to hear that!

Comment: thanks for answer me bro :D!, anyway it can be taken as a useful answer (the one you answered) ;)